# How to Query CRM 2011 EntityCollection in LINQ

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to query a EntityCollection / PartyList using LINQs and have had no luck figuring out how to do it.

My query is:

```
var linqQuery = (from r in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("campaignresponse")
                 select new

                 {
                     activityid = !r.Contains("activityid") ? string.Empty : r["activityid"],
                     CustomerId = !r.Contains("customer") ? string.Empty : r["customer"]
                 });
```

CustomerId is the PartyList / EntityCollection. If I run that code I get, `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityCollection` instead of my actual data. Any ideas on how to query the EntityCollection in LINQ and return the data? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `EntityCollection` has the property `Entities` which contains the retrieved data.

[EntityCollection.Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.entitycollection.entities.aspx)

---

**Edit:**

So for example:

```
        var result = service.RetrieveMultiple(query).Entities
            .Select(e => 
                new 
                { 
                    firstname = e.Attributes["firstname"],
                    lastname = e.Attributes["lastname"]
                });
```

Comment: Thanks. I gave CustomerId = !r.Contains("customer") ? string.Empty : ((EntityCollection)r["customer"]).Entities.ToString() a try and it returned Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.DataCollection`1[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity]. Any idea how I get to the data? Thanks again.